# How to convert field values to columns in excel? (No transpose)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

In Excel, I have below table, with columns 1, 2, 3 as the ranks of the keywords in search engine.

[image]

How can I convert the above table into the following format

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUMPRODUCT()` formula like below. Drag and drop down and right as needed.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$D$1)*($A$2:$A$4=$A8)*($B$2:$D$4=B$7))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain it as I have an excel file contains one sheet that has the above data (1st table) in large volume, thereby I have to make 2nd sheet to populate target table.

Comment: Read these articles. [Article 1](https://exceljet.net/formula/sumproduct-with-if), [Article 2](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function)

Comment: @AniketGhole If you found the answer useful then consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.